# How To Modify A Range of Cells Without a Loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I have a massive Excel template that's having performance issues. I'd like to optimize the VBA code I'm using to modify cells to be more of an "all at once" approach. I have several basic functions using loops to modify values. Here's an example:

```
Dim aCell as Range
For Each aCell In Range("A1:A9999").Cells

    'appends prefix to value of each cell
     aCell.Value = "CC_" & aCell.Value

Next aCell
```

While this works, the drawback of this is that it causes several recalculations and updates that slows down the template. I'm familiar with turning calculations/screen updating on and off, but for reasons I won't go into, that's not an option.

This code below does **NOT** work, but it's the approach I'm looking for. Is there a way to make such a change using an array or some other tool I'm not thinking of that would minimize the templates calculation updates?

```
Range("A1:A9999").Value = "CC_" & Range("A1:A9999").Value
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading/writing to/from the worksheet takes a lot of time. Do the modifications within a VBA array, then write it back.

```
Dim myRange As Range, myArr As Variant
Set myRange = Range("A1:A9999")

myArr = myRange

For i = 1 To UBound(myArr, 1)
    myArr(i, 1) = "CC_" & myArr(i, 1)
Next i

myRange = myArr
```

Comment: Another modification that might speed it up is to set `myRange` dynamically to include only the range to be processed.

Comment: Yea the range of A1:A9999 is just an example. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily create a column full of functions, then paste those values over the column A values:

```
Range("XFD1:xfd9999").Formula = "=""CC_""&A1"
Calculate
Range("A1:a9999").Value = Range("XFD1:XFD8").Value
Range("XFD1:XFD9999").ClearContents
```

I'm operating on the assumption here that you are not using column XFD for anything else. If you are, you could use a different column for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I will give you a tick, but I should have specified "without using a helper column."

Comment: Thanks. The helper column helpfully vanishes afterwards. Nobody needs to know.

Comment: I would disagree that people wouldn't know. The scroll bar might act under the assumption that the usedRange extends to the final column. People most definitely notice things like that.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you can do it without a loop using `Evaluate` like this:

```
Sub addText()
     With Range("A1:A9999")
        .Value2 = .Worksheet.Evaluate("INDEX(""CC_""&" & .Address & ",)")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI `Evaluate("""C_"" & " & .Address)` without the INDEX() also works fine

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks. The INDEX was force of habit as a lot of functions need a little coercion to return arrays of values.

Answer (score 0):

I was revisiting this (trying to still make it faster) and now that I have a little better understanding, I would recommend an approach shown below. The accepted answer is hard-coded for one column, which was my example asked, but the below approach is more dynamic.

```
Sub sampleArraySheetEdit()
Dim aRange As Range: Set aRange = Range("A1:B9999") ' or whatever your range is...
Dim vRng() As Variant: vRng = aRange
Dim r As Long, c As Long


For r = LBound(vRng, 1) To UBound(vRng, 1) 'this ensures all cells always accounted for
    For c = LBound(vRng, 2) To UBound(vRng, 2)

        'perform you operation here....
        vRng(r, c) = "CC_" & vRng(r, c)

    Next c
Next r

aRange = vRng

End Sub
```