# PasteSpecial alternatives for better performance?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that is highly inefficient in copying data from one sheet to another.

```
Sheets("Repository").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

How can I rewrite this piece of copy above in a more performance efficient way while keeping the options (xlPastevalues, Operation, SkipBlanks and Transpose)?

Using the `Sheets("Repository").Copy` Destination does not seem preserve the options and format neither is it much more efficient.

Comment: If you want more efficient don't use copy, paste

Comment: How about `Sheets("Repository").Range("A1:D100").Value = Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("A1:D100").Value` ? You need to modify the range according to your code's needs

Comment: I would like to understand what do you mean by "highly inefficient"

Comment: Oh @PGSystemTester The question was directed to the OP. I wanted to understand what did he mean by "highly efficient" :)

Comment: Well if we wanted to be truly efficient he would learn how to use arrays and go down that rabbit hole. Who doesnt like building data sets on the fly? :D

Comment: @Error: I am also confused by your question. On one end you want to paste only values (`xlPasteValues`) and on the other hand at the end of your question you are wanting to preserve options/formats?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to simply do `xlPasteValues` withhout anything fancy like transpose or skip blanks, then setting the value equal to the other value is probably the easiest and most efficient option.

Example of copying `A1:B10` sheet1 to column `D1:E10` in Sheet2.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D1:E10").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Value
```

If you have to make a lot of edits, you might consider inserting them in an array first, [here's an example from a question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154365/how-to-modify-a-range-of-cells-without-a-loop).

Also, in answer to the comment *I would like to understand what do you mean by "highly inefficient"*:
Using copy/paste uses a lot of overhead resources of your computer (not Excel). It  has to capture the entire cell attributes, formatting, values, formulas, and display the marching dots. Simply setting the value, or finding some way to avoid using the computer's Copy method avoids overhead slowdown and extensive screen updating.

Comment: Well technically the application UI is what is reserving the cpu needed to make the extra communication between the front and and the back end. So while you are partially correct, it is in fact Excel's fault :P <3

Comment: One of my cardinal sins/rules/dumb guidlines for VBA coding is "Do not interact with the Application's Objects (if you can avoid it)." This goes for all MS applications that are vba capable.

Comment: @DougCoats indeed. I say "Don't touch excel". Yours sounds more sophisticated. I was actually going to make an article on this for thespreadsheetguru. Haven't gotten around to it yet. Most people survive by just looping lines/rows and making the edits there.